# which is better? - 3 ways to add an entry to a map

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

I have the following code in `sourceFile.cpp`. `functionA()` is first called and inserted entries for key1, key2 and key3. Then `functionB()` gets called to use the vectors for the 3 keys. I want to free all memory after exiting `functionC()`. Among the three ways to put an entry into the map for the 3 keys, which is correct / better?

```
Class ClassA { ... }

ClassA *key1 = new ClassA();
ClassA *key2 = new ClassA();
ClassA *key3 = new ClassA();

static map<ClassA*, vector<pair<char*, char*> > > stringMap;

// which way of adding an entry into StringMap is better? key1, key2 or key3
void functionA() {
    // insert entries into stringMap for key1 and key2
    vector<pair<char*, char*> > *v1 = new vector<pair<char*, char*> >();
    stringMap[key1] = *v1;
    stringMap[key2]; // map will insert one vector<pair<char*, char*> > object
    // is this vector object on heap or stack?

    vector<pair<char*, char*> > v3;
    stringMap[key3] = v3; // 
}

void functionB() {
    // get entries for key1, key2 and key3
    // use vector.push_back() to populate vectors
}

void functionC() {
    // so when program exits this function, all memory is released
    vector<pair<char*, char*> > *v1 = stringMap[key1];
    v1->clear(); // or loop and v1->erase() 
    stringMap.erase(key1);
    delete v1;

    vector<pair<char*, char*> > v2 = stringMap[key2];
    v2.clear();
    stringMap.erase(key2);
    // v2 was inserted by map, does it need to delete v2 ??? 

    // what about the vector for key3?
}
```

Comment: do you have to use pointer?

Comment: "better" is _not_ a measurable quantity. Better in what way? Functional, faster, cleaner code, etc?

Comment: You're asking a lot of questions in the comments of the code, and some parts (like `functionB`) are left blank except for comments. Do you need all of them answered?

Comment: In general, it is best to use `insert()`. Using `[]` syntax will default create a copy of the map value, and then copy the value in, which is usually inefficient. Regarding your questions: any time you use 'new' you are allocating on the heap. Every time you use `new` you should use `delete`, or even better, put the `new`'ed object in a smart pointer (`std::shared_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr`).

Comment: I really think you're approaching C++ from the wrong angle.

Comment: These functions are related to my question. The purpose of this map is to store all pairs when feeding data to an object of ClassA. I have many instances of ClassA. After an object of ClassA completes its work, the memory stored in the map will be released. Thanks.

Comment: @paddy. Can you please explain?

Comment: Well, I can tell one thing right off the bat: [read this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6101039/Modern%20C%2B%2B.pdf) and also [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization). Interestingly enough, tucked deep in both are several points that relate to your questions (but in one, you gotta dig deep).

Comment: @paxdiablo regarding correctness, memory management, and speed. thx

Comment: @BenSmith It's just that you're going pointer-crazy, as if you've discovered a cool new toy and you're throwing it around on the concrete without understanding how fragile it is.  With respect, you need to do some ground-work in C++ before you tackle pointers and containers in this manner.  I get the feeling that you know a bit of C, and thought that C++ magically makes all the difficult memory stuff go away, so you just jumped in the deep end.  You will not be able to get useful answers if you are too far out of your depth.

Comment: @paddy Thanks for your comments. I come from Java world. We have a C++ library, and use JNI to communicate. We feed data to C++ object (ClassA). There are some other Java objects and C++ objects need to be freed after the C++ object (ClassA) completes its work. I use map to store the pairs of C++ object (ClassA) pointer and a vector of Java object and C++ object. You may give me a better solution.

Comment: @Ben - You try to write Java in C++, making it look *really* odd for those of us that are used to C++. More like an old Google translate from Chinese to French. You need to have a C++ programmer help you here.